# How to print RichEditBox with PrintHelper?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit, winui

I want to Print RichEditBox, i am using Windows Community Toolkit helper class called PrintHelper.
i tested this code:

```
<Grid x:Name="PrintableContent">
  <RichEditBox Name="txt"/>
</Grid>
```

and

```
txt.Document.SetText(Microsoft.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, long text);

_printHelper = new PrintHelper(PrintableContent);
var printHelperOptions = new PrintHelperOptions(false);
printHelperOptions.Orientation = PrintOrientation.Default;
await _printHelper.ShowPrintUIAsync(WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(this), "Windows Community Toolkit Sample App", printHelperOptions, true);
```

The problem is that not all text is printed And only the visible part is printed
[image]

How can I print all available text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior for the Print function. The print API can't print the invisible text. The print function is like a screenshot. If you want to show all the text, you have to make all the text visible.